# Changing from an HTTP post to an HTTPS post with PHP

Tags: php, html, http, https

First off, I'm a complete novice as a web developer.  I have a PHP function that handles a post request for HTTP, and it works great.  I read a few places online that all I have to do to make that same function post to HTTPS is change the port I'm hitting from port 80 to port 443.  So instead of looking like this:

```
$fp = fsockopen($host, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

It would look like this:

```
$fp = fsockopen($host, 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

Unfortunately, this change doesn't seem to be working.  So my questions are these:

Is it true that all I have to change is the port number?

If there is more to do, than what is it I still need to do?

Please try to keep things in as simple terms as possible, since I am the first to admit I'm very new to this kind of stuff.

Thanks a ton everyone.

Comment: Have you read the notes about SSL in the PHP manual? http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get SSL working in fsockopen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757957/how-do-i-get-ssl-working-in-fsockopen)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it true that all I have to change is the port number?

No

> If there is more to do, than what is it I still need to do?

You have to negotiate an SSL connection and tunnel the HTTP request through it.

Don't try to do this with sockets. Use a library designed for it, such as [cURL](http://php.net/curl).

Comment: I also think cURL is probably a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

From php.net:

> If OpenSSL support is installed, you may prefix the hostname with either ssl:// or tls:// to use an SSL or TLS client connection over TCP/IP to connect to the remote host.

Try prepending ssl:// to your $host (but also keeping port 443;

Comment: So I added the ssl:// to the front of the $host string.  Now I can hit the server, but I get back an error:
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: nginx/1.0.4
Date: Sun, 04 Sep 2011 00:12:46 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 10
Connection: close, 404 error

Do I need to format the data I'm sending differently because I'm going over SSL now?

Comment: I'm not sure. I see "404 error" which makes me think you're not requesting the right URL.