# php HTTP tunnel to IMAP/POP3 using SSL

Tags: php, email, ssl, zend-framework, proxy

My code should check email boxes via proxy with PHP using SSL.

[`Zend\Mail`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-mail) package provides implementation of both protocols without php extention and fits fine.

I partially override [`connect()`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-mail/blob/master/src/Protocol/Pop3.php#L70-L123) method by code:

```
$this->socket = fsockopen($proxy, $proxy_port, $errno, $errstr, self::TIMEOUT_CONNECTION);
$this->sendRequest("CONNECT {$host}:{$port} HTTP/1.1");
$this->sendRequest("Host: {$host}:{$port}");
$this->sendRequest($userAgent);
$this->sendRequest("Proxy-Authorization: basic " . base64_encode("$user:$pass") . "\r\n");

// Remove 2 lines with proxy response
fgets($this->socket);
fgets($this->socket);
```

With unsecure connection everything works fine, but not works for secured port.
Connections on 110 port rejected by server with "please use SSL/TLS", when script tries to connect on secure port 995, nothing happend, no any response from mail server.

Probably, I missed one more HTTP header or so.

Anybody knows which command need send to end server through HTTP tunnel to start SSL connection?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757957/how-do-i-get-ssl-working-in-fsockopen

Comment: PS: Just because you're connecting to a port which is meant to be used for ssl connections, *does not* mean that fsockopen knows that it should now use SSL.