# PySocks proxy auhtentication failed

Tags: python, sockets, proxy, imap

I'm still try create imap\pop3 proxied client. First try is on PHP is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35018585/php-http-tunnel-to-imap-pop3-using-ssl).
Now I try the same with python.

I found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3387230/1812335), which good fits, so my code based is on [stackowerflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3387230/1812335) and it work for proxy without authentication:

```
class SocksIMAP4SSL(IMAP4_SSL):
    def open(self, host, port=IMAP4_SSL_PORT):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.sock = create_connection(dest_pair=(host, port), proxy_type=PROXY_TYPE_HTTP, proxy_addr=PROXY_IP,
                                      proxy_port=PROXY_PORT, proxy_rdns=True, proxy_username=PROXY_AUTH_LOGIN,
                                      proxy_password=PROXY_AUTH_PASS)
        # self.sock = socket.create_connection((host, port))
        self.sslobj = ssl.wrap_socket(self.sock, self.keyfile, self.certfile)
        self.file = self.sslobj.makefile('rb')
```

But if I use proxy with authentication it always fail by reason:

```
socks.HTTPError: 407: Proxy Authentication Required
```

Proxy auth type: basic. Both login and password is correct. 
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is this `create_connection()` method? Where do you implement it?

Comment: ```from socks import create_connection```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used https://github.com/Anorov/PySocks, but It does not support basic authentication for HTTP proxy. A few lines solves this issue:

```
http_headers = [
    b"Connect %s:%s HTTP/1.1" % (addr.encode('idna'), str(dest_port).encode()),
    b"Host: %s" % dest_addr.encode('idna')
]

if username and password:
    http_headers.append(b"Proxy-Authorization: basic %s" % str(b64encode("%s:%s" % (username, password))))

http_headers.append(b"\r\n")

self.sendall(b"\r\n".join(http_headers))
```